# "Tag <Activity > attribute name has invalid character ' '. " Android Manifest

Tags: java, android, manifest

I am getting the error "Tag  attribute name has invalid character ' '. " in the Android Manifest, while there is no obviously invalid character. Here is the code:

```
<activity
        android:name="Quiz 31"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="Quiz 31"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.SoulSlayerAbad.AMQ.QUIZ31" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

As you can see, no ' ' character in the code. Does anyone know why this is happening? One thing to note is that I generated this piece of code using a few lines of Java run inside of Eclipse console. The code for that is:

```
        int Begin = 0, End = 0; 
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String Text = " <activity "+
            "android:name=\"Quiz "+Begin+"\" "+
            "android:configChanges=\"orientation|keyboardHidden\" "+
            "android:label=\"Quiz "+Begin+"\" "+
            "android:screenOrientation=\"portrait\" "+
            "android:theme=\"@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar\" > "+
            "<intent-filter> "+
                "<action android:name=\"com.SoulSlayerAbad.AMQ.QUIZ"+Begin+"\" /> "+

                "<category android:name=\"android.intent.category.DEFAULT\" /> "+
            "</intent-filter> "+
        "</activity> ";

    System.out.println("Begining:");
    Begin = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("End At:");
    End = sc.nextInt();
    while(Begin <= End){
        System.out.println(Text);
        Begin++;
    }
```

Comment: change quiz 31 per quiz_31

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`android:name` is supposed to have reference of your class path which represents the activity. It must not contain any special characters or spaces.

For example:

```
android:name="com.json.test.MainActivity"
```

Here, `MainActivity` is the class file which extends an `Activity`.

Comment: I had this problem and deleted the activity and asked it to safe delete (with usage search). Now it is deleted, except for in the manifest. I cannot remove it from the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Your name attribute should contain your activity class:

> android:name
>       The name of the class that implements the activity, a subclass of Activity. The attribute value should be a fully qualified class name
>   (such as, "com.example.project.ExtracurricularActivity")

Answer (score 1):

`android:name` can't contain white spaces, it's the name of a class.

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters you're missing an escaped quote; are you sure that code compiles?

```
"<action android:name=\"com.SoulSlayerAbad.AMQ.QUIZ"+Begin+"\" /> "+
```

Slash missing before the double quote just before `+Begin`.

Secondly, if you actually *aren't* missing that slash, but when you pasted it here it made it look like it, perhaps an odd control character made it into that line.

Try deleting that line and retyping it from scratch.

You could also open your manifest file in a hex editor and verify that no strange non-printable characters are mixed in.

Answer (score 0):

your `android:name` does not contain white spaces or special characters. for example android name should be like this

```
<activity  
android:name="com.example.users.projectname.MainActivity">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

In additional  `package` is also needed to be named in English alphabet other case AndroidManifest gives similar error. That I experienced